# How to drop dataframe rows not in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a:

1. Dataframe df1 with columns A, B and C. A is the index.
2. Dataframe df2 with columns D, E and F. D is the index.

What’s an efficient way to drop from df1 all rows where B is not found in df2 (in D the index)?

Comment: a left merge is obvious answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need drop some not exist values it is same like select only existing values. So is possible use:

You can filter `df1.B` by index from `df2` in [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df3 = df1[df1.B.isin(df2.index)]
```

Or by [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2[[]], left_on='B', right_index=True, how='left')
```

Comment: @simpatico - Is possible use `df3 = df1.merge(df2[[]], left_on='B', right_index=True, how='left')` ?

Comment: `df1 = df1[df1['B'].isin(df2.index)]` worked for me